# Print python-socketio events infos using decorators

Tags: python, socket.io, python-socketio

I would like to improve the `socketio.event` decorator to make it print the event fired and its parameters.
I have a `Manager` class which has a `self.sio: socketio.Server` attribute. I try to define a new decorator as a `Manager` method such as it returns a function decorated by `self.sio.event`and which also prints its data. I have tried this solution, but it does not work :

```py
    def event(self, func):
        @self.sio.event
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f'[{func.__name__}] : {args} {kwargs}')
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

Any recommendation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work for you:

```py
    def event(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f'[{func.__name__}] : {args} {kwargs}')
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.sio.on(func.__name__, wrapper)
```

You can't really use the `@sio.event` on the wrapper, because then the event that will be configured is going to be named `wrapper`. My solution uses the `@sio.on` decorator, which accepts the event name explicitly.